# How to sort one list based on another list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two separate lists one list contain list of lists(list1) and another list is simple numeric values.
The list2 is sorted but i want to sort list1 based on the values of list2 .Using Zip method it is gives errors:unhashable type.

```
list1=[[1 ,2],[2,1],[1,3],[1,9],[6,9],[3,5],[6,8],[4,5],[7,9]]
list2=[0.0,1.4142135623730951,1.0,7.0,8.602325267042627, 3.605551275463989,7.810249675906654,4.242640687119285,9.219544457292887]
keydict=dict(zip(list1,list2))//Gives errror: unhashable type
```

.Can Anybody suggest solution.

Comment: _The list2 is sorted_ : **no** - it is not `0.0 <1.4142135623730951 > 1.0 ...` - unclear. There is a plethora of questions on SO of sorting lists based on other lists, based on objects-attributes in other lists etc. This is a dupe - did none other post help you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below list comprehension:

```
print([list1[list2.index(i)] for i in sorted(list2)])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [3, 5], [4, 5], [1, 9], [6, 8], [6, 9], [7, 9]]
```

Comment: It'd probably be cheaper to make a lookup table for `list2` mapping value to index than to do this...

Comment: @AdamSmith How...

Comment: This is giving wrong output for `list2 = [0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,7.0,8.602325267042627...]` for example, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip()` + `sorted()`:

```
[x for x, _ in sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

**Code**:

```
list1 = [[1 ,2],[2,1],[1,3],[1,9],[6,9],[3,5],[6,8],[4,5],[7,9]]
list2 = [0.0,1.4142135623730951,1.0,7.0,8.602325267042627, 3.605551275463989,7.810249675906654,4.242640687119285,9.219544457292887]

print([x for x, _ in sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda x: x[1])])
# [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [3, 5], [4, 5], [1, 9], [6, 8], [6, 9], [7, 9]]
```